# Data with too many categories

Tags: python, r

I hope to know a general approach when do data engineering.

I have a data set with some variables with too many categories, and including these variables into a predictive model definitely would increase the complexity of the model, thus leads to overfit.

While normally I would group those categories into fewer groups by drawing plots to see **if the response variable is significantly different among these groups**. Is there a more efficient way dealing with this issue, like automatically carry out some statistical test?

**ADDED: In a nutshell, I hope to group or bin values in a variable  so that the response variable in each group has very different distribution.**

Comment: Could the principal component analysis solve your problem?

Comment: [related](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/146907/principled-way-of-collapsing-categorical-variables-with-many-categories)

Comment: Thanks. PCA is generally used to reduce the dimension of variables. But my problem is based on one variable. For example, I wanna predict the petal length by the type of flowers, but there are thousands of types, So can I group them in terms of petal length?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand by "automatically". However, instead of plotting (which can be a hard task if you have many attributes for each sample), you can try to automatically group your samples using clustering techniques such as K-Means, Hierarchical clustering, SOM (or any clustering technique that fits to your problem). Then, for each group, you may extract any statistical information of interest.